# Storing Custom Class type array in Coredata

Tags: arrays, swift, core-data, transformable

I am trying to store custom class type array in coredata.

What I've got setup is an Entity called `Node` with properties `value` of type string and `children` of type `Transformable`. The `children` property is supposed to store an array of type `Node` as in the code below.

```
public class Node: NSManagedObject {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Node> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Node>(entityName: "Person")
    }

    @NSManaged public var children: [Node]?
    @NSManaged public var value: String?

}
```

`.xcdatamodel` setup:

[image]

Currently the app crashes with error message "This decoder will only decode classes that adopt NSSecureCoding. Class 'Node' does not adopt it."
So I tried it with String array instead of Node array and it seems to work.

I'm guessing something extra needs to be done to store Custom array type.

Comment: I think you are doing this wrong, add "children" as an one-to-many relationship pointing back to Node instead of using an array attribute.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson will look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want a recursive data structure, where each node can have many other nodes as children and another node as its parent. This is what CoreData relationships are for.

Under your `Node` entity:

1. Add a relationship `children` of type "To Many" with destination `Node`. No inverse.
2. Add a relationship `parent` of Type "To One" with destination `Node`, set its inverse to `children`
3. Go back to the `children` relationship and set its inverse to `parent`
4. Consider what the delete rules should be. I suggest "Cascade" for `children`, meaning if you delete a parent all of its children are deleted too. "Nullify" makes sense for `parent`, meaning if you delete a child it just removes the parent's connection to that one child.

Comment: As ```children``` for every ```Node``` is of type ```NSSet``` how could one display them a table view?

Comment: @unknown check the "ordered" box for arrangement to get an ordered set. Then you should be able to pretty easily match them up with indices in a table view

Comment: Setting ```children``` relationships arrangement to ordered throws error "Node.children must not be ordered". Any idea on how to proceed?

Comment: Apparently, relationships with ordered arrangement  cannot be used while using cloud kit. Is there an alternative way?

Comment: @unknown Add a `sortOrder` attribute to your Nodes and implement `Comparable` for them using that. Then you have a standard way to order them for table views.

Comment: That seems to be an inconvenient method, is there a way to make ```children``` return an array?

Comment: @unknown not that I know of. Usually in this situation I'll name the relationship something like `childrenSet` and then make a virtual property that gets/sets it using an array instead

Comment: One could easily add a computed property that converts the Set to a sorted Array

Comment: Did what @JoakimDanielson suggested and that seems to work.

Comment: I'm using an array to store ```Node``` items. And loading the data to the array from core data. However, I'm seeing some weird behaviour where ```fetchRequest``` returns all the parent as well as children Nodes. This is the first time I'm using relationships, so I'm not sure this is normal behaviour.

Comment: @unknown if you're just fetching `Node`, that is expected. It will return all `Node` entities in the database, including parents and children. If you want to remember the specific parent node so that you can retrieve it later you should record its `objectId` somewhere so you can query for that specific entity